# Random Battery Voltage Drops

Tags: electrical, electronic-control-module

I have a 2008 Pegout 207 that does not start anymore, since the car has parked for a while, I assumed it was the battery (the battery icon was flashing).
Even with a new battery the car does not start, and it complains on the dashboard of a weak battery.

I connected to the ODB Port and while there are no error codes on ECU, the Battery Voltage is very weird:

[image]

There drops that can go down to 7.5Volts, randomly, this happens, without any cranking, or turn on and off devices. Monitoring the battery directly I see some steady 12.7 volts.

What do you think this may be?

Comment: Is the new battery fully charged? Are the battery connections clean and tight?

Comment: @Moab yes, there is voltage, also on the old one is fine, I did clean all the connections with electrical cleaner spray.

Comment: I asked if it was fully charged, not what the voltage is.

Comment: You check the battery connections are good, by slackening them just enough to twizzle the connectors around the battery terminal posts, so that metal scrapes against metal, and then retightening. Electrical cleaner spray is for switch contacts etc.

Comment: @Moab yes, I did charge it with the battery charger

Comment: @WeatherVane I did do that, there is spark, even when connecting to to battery